# D3js map: Antarctic landmass fill artifact?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I'm using D3js to make a map of Köppen-Geiger climate classifications, but for some reason, the overlay over Antarctica is only partially filling in the continent. **An in-progress version [is on github here](http://rawgithub.com/circleofconfusion/climate-map/master/climate.html)**

[image]

Both the shapefiles for the world map and climate map seem to be correctly set up when opened in QGIS, and they seem to convert to GeoJSON properly. I tried converting the files to GeoJSON instead of TopoJSON, but got the same result.

I got the climate maps from [here](http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/shifts.htm)

My suspicion is that something is incorrectly set up in my code. There was an extra complication in that I needed to add a clip path to the climate layer since the shape files have squared edges that bleed out into the ocean, which doesn't look very nice. To bring in the shape files, I'm using the following function:

```
function loadOverlay(overlayFile) {
    d3.json(overlayFile, function (error, climate) {

        // remove the old overlay if it exists
        svg.selectAll(".overlay")
            .remove();

        // add new overlay to the map
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class","overlay") // set the class
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)") // use the shoreline paths as a clip path
            .selectAll(".climate")
                .data (topojson.feature(climate, climate.objects.features).features) // load the overlay from topoJSON
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                    // set the Climate type from the gridcode feature property in the topoJSON file
                    .attr("class",function (d) { 
                        return "climate " + d.properties.gridcode;
                    })
                    .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
                    .attr("title", function (d) {
                        return d.properties.gridcode;
                    });
    });
}
```

Comment: Which version of D3js do you use. This is a known bug, if I remember well, Mike fixed this in the 3.3.3 versions. I don't remember clearly.

Comment: I'm just linking to the library on the d3js website:

`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I can't find out where I saw a post about this precise issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use adaptive resampling, as Mike describes here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/example/

Comment: @circleofconfusio : Middle of the page. Mike made posts in June about these fill issues. Keywords seems to be resample/resampling. But I now wonder if it's not 's your data as well. The bug, indeed, should still design more than this current area. Last : for such large areas as oceans, please use modern web color for water bodies, #C6ECFF is a good choice.